# Zend DB: joinLeft problem

Tags: zend-framework, mysql, zend-db

I am trying to construct this query with Zend DB:

```
SELECT
    `s` . * ,
    `a` . *
FROM 
    `shr_statement` AS  `s`
LEFT JOIN  
    `shr_answer` AS a`
ON 
    a.statement_id = s.statement_id 
    AND
    a.user_id =1
WHERE
    (s.language =  'en_US') AND (s.is_active =1 )
ORDER BY 
    `order` ASC
```

I read about a possible issue with the double 'ON' statement ...

Thanks!

Comment: What's your actual question or did you just want someone to code your query for you?

Comment: Hi, No, not at all :-). I had a problem with joinLeft and was wondering how you could code it. I finally solved it by the answer here and an alias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick, where $db is an instance of your Zend_Db adapter

```
$select = $db->select()
    ->from(array('s' => 'shr_statement'))
    ->joinLeft(array('a' => 'shr_answer'), 'a.statement_id = s.statement_id')
    ->where('s.language = ?', 'en_US')
    ->where('s.is_active = ?', 1)
    ->where('a.user_id = ?', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're missing the left backtick from your alias.. ie it should be "`shr_answer` AS `a`".

Or even better get rid of all your backticks. They are evil and unnecessary! ;)